# Is there a way to use ! operator in prolog using predicates only in prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
isa(X,Y) :- X=Y.
isa(X,Y) :- isaLink(X,Y).
isa(X,Z) :- isaLink(X,Y), isa(Y,Z).

mostSpecificSubsumer(X,Y,Z) :- isa(X,Y), isa(Y,A), !, A=Z.
```

I am trying to get the least common ancestor(mostSpecificSubsumer), although in my assignment I am not allowed to use the ! cut operator. Is there a way I can add some rules in prolog to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using the cut operator, you add predicates that test the outcome already handled by the other clauses. E.g. in the second and third clauses, add X = Y so that if the first clause applies to a given couple of variables (X, Y), then the second and third clauses would not apply.

Your isa/2 would look like this:

```
isa(X,Y) :- X=Y.
isa(X,Y) :- X \=Y, isaLink(X,Y), \+ isa(Y, Y).
isa(X,Z) :- X \=Y, isaLink(X,Y), isa(Y, Z).
```

The not operator in the second clause is to negate the isa in the third clause. I haven't tested the above code since I don't have a specific request to test. So try it yourself and tell us about it.